# 3D Matrices - How to "Wobble" an object?

Tags: matrix, 3d

I'm trying to make a 3D object do a wobble effect, very much like a boss in StarFox 64 did when it teleported (see [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mizb8ZCDjsE) at 5:17 for reference). This seems like either a skewing effect, or perhaps an un-uniform scale that rotated around and was applied without rotating the object itself.

Does anyone have any idea how this might be done, or perhaps does anyone have any links to programs where I can play with the matrices directly to see how this is done?

Answer (score 0):

You can use skew based on roll axis in the Euler angles coordinate system
See Euler angles
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_angles

Euler angles-matrix transformation ("General rotations" part of the article):
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix

An euler angles-matrix conversion utility in DirectX SDK
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsmobile.directx.matrix.rotationyawpitchroll%28v=VS.85%29.aspx

And threads about skew matrices

[skew matrix algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673216/skew-matrix-algorithm)

http://www.quantunet.com/flash8/knowledgebase/actionscript/advanced/matrix/matrix_skew.html