# How to find the transformation matrix for given scale, skew, and translation values?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, math, matrix

### How is a transformation matrix defined?

I have the values defining scale, skew, and translation. I would like to find the transformation matrix they represent.

- Scale x/y can be any number.
- Translation x/y can be any number.
- Skew x/y is in degrees between -180 and 180.

**How can I find the transformation matrix for these values?**

I am working with values from Flash, and would like the matrix to be formatted like this, so that I can export this matrix and apply the same transformation in another language :

```
| a c u |
| b d v |
| 0 0 1 |
```

**I need to be able to go from the parameters to the matrix outside of AS3/JSFL/Flash.**

(Specifically I want to use C#, but I want an answer that doesn't depend on a given language.)

This link talks about how matrices work in Flash, and I understand most of it. However from what I can tell, it does not describe how to go from position/scale/skew values to a matrix.
http://www.senocular.com/flash/tutorials/transformmatrix/

I know there is a .matrix property of flash display objects, but I am working with the given values outside of flash, and need to find a solution without using that.

### Actionscript's skew is misbehaving

Given the usual definitions of tranformations in Cimbali's answer, I'm still having problems with building a matrix from its skew parameter.

Here is an example set of data:

**A) Object Properties (logged directly from [Flash using JSFL](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flash/cs/extend/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9024f3f-7f6cCS5.html), [element.x](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flash/cs/extend/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9024f3f-7fbaCS5.html), [element.skewX](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flash/cs/extend/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9024f3f-7fbeCS5.html), etc...)**

```
x: 0
y: 0
scaleX: 1
scaleY: 1.0000152587890625
skewX: 19.9998779296875
skewY: 0
```

**B) Transform Matrix (logged directly from Flash using JSFL, [element.matrix](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flash/cs/extend/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9024f3f-7cc7CS5.html))**

```
1      | 0      | 0     
-0.342 | 0.94   | 0     
0      | 0      | 1
```

**Here is what I tried:**

```
sx = tan(19.9998779296875 * PI / 180) = tan(0.34906372) = 0.36396782164

Scale Matrix        Skew X Matrix       Result Matrix
1 | 0 | 0           1    | 0 | 0        1    | 0 | 0
0 | 1 | 0      x    0.36 | 1 | 0    =   0.36 | 1 | 0
0 | 0 | 1           0    | 0 | 0        0    | 0 | 1
```

SkewY is 0, so there's no reason to multiply again using a Skew Y Matrix.

**So why is my Result Matrix so much different than the matrix posted by Flash?**

In this example my graphic is originally 200 x 100 px. It does not inherit transformations from any parent (the parent is definitely not transformed in any way). However, when I place the graphic on the stage and ONLY change the skew X value to 20°, the Height in the properties panel changes from100 to 94px, but Scale Y stays at 100%.

In case you're not familiar with Flash IDE, when you adjust ONLY the skew X value, it does not simply push the corners of the graphic left/right. It actually makes the corners move on an arc, as you increase skew X, the parallelogram comes shorter vertically.

(I realize I have rounded some numbers, but that is only for ease of displaying them here.)

Comment: The matrix you compute is correct, given the input skew, though they seem to take the opposite angle (`tan(-19.99...)`). The matrix JSFL spits out seems incorrect, or at least seems to be the "concatenation" of your matrix with one that is scaling the Y axis by 0.94 (`0.36396782164 * 0.94 = 0.342` and `1*0.94 = 0.94`). Is there a container, parent element, or anything at all that might explain this supplementary scaling ? Is it the same on other examples ?

Comment: Interesting. Yes my graphic is originally 200 x 100 px. It does have a parent, but the parent is definitely not transformed in any way. However, when I place the graphic on the stage and ONLY change the skew X value to 20°, the Height in the properties panel changes from100 to 94px, but Scale Y stays at 100%. Ugh.

Comment: In case you're not familiar with Flash IDE, when you adjust ONLY the skew X value, it does not simply push the corners of the graphic left/right. It actually makes the corners move on an arc, as you increase skew X, the parallelogram comes shorter vertically.

Comment: I should clarify that values discussed in these comments are from the IDE panels, while the values in my post are from JSFL code logging properties of the graphic.

Comment: Dustin : ok, that's interesting, and not exactly a skew. We have indeed `cos(0.34906372) = 0.9396` so it seems to fit. I will update my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Applying successive transformations is, for some strange reason, called "concatenating matrices" in actionscript 3, which as your link explains, and is done by multiplying matrices : read section "Matrix Multiplication" completely : it starts by defining matrix multiplications and ends litteraly by `A*B -> B.concat(A);`.

Note that the order in which transformations are applied is important : B*A is not A*B. In both `A*B` and `B.concat(A);`, `B` is applied before `A`. You can think of it as  `A*(B*(x,y,1))` thanks to the associativity of the matrix product. This is also explained in the section "Concatenated Matrices" of your link, where a child element is transformed by its matrix, and then by its parent matrix, which is shown to be equivalent to a single transformation by `child_matrix.concat(parent_matrix);`

However the missing piece of the puzzle is that for each operation you describe, there is a corresponding transformation matrix. They are all [illustrated and explained in adobe's reference on Matrices](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/geom/Matrix.html). There is however a small mistake on the illustration of skew matrices, you should refer [to this stackoverflow question instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673216/skew-matrix-algorithm).

Here is the illustration from [the wikipedia page on the topic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_transformation#Affine_transformation_in_plane_geometry), which is just as clear :

[image: formulas/matrices for different kind of plane transformations from wikipedia]

Note that all reflections can be expressed by scaling with W and/or H having -1 value. For shear expressed as angles, just use `A = tan(a)` in the images above.

---

However, it seems that flash disagrees on the meaning of "skew", and instead of preserving one coordinate while skewing the other, it preserves *the lengths that were originally along that coordinate*. Or, as you describe it, if you skew along X a rectangle, (some of) its vertices aren't pushed left or right, but move on an arc.

As it seems, they skew one coordinate, *then* correct the elongation of the figure by scaling the other coordinate. Luckily the factor by which this happens is easily predictable since we know trigonometry : it is the cosine of the angle.

So whenever you have a skewX by an angle `a` in flash, you have to use the following product of matrices (expressed using definitions from the image above) : `matrix(scale with W=1 and H=cos(a)) * matrix(skew along x with A=-tan(a))`

It would only be logical that defining a skewY in flash would yield in a reasonable programming language `matrix(scale with W=cos(a) and H=1) * matrix(skew along y with B=-tan(a))`

Comment: First, thanks for all your help! I understand that A * B is not equal to B * A, but how do i know if I should do scaleMatrix * skewXMatrix * skewYMatrix, or some other order?

Comment: So the "correct" way would be whatever way results in the same matrix that Flash spits out, right? I'm still not fully grasping the calculations, I guess. I updated the original post with some example values, and my attempt at following your advice.