# UILabel with skewed text on iOS

Tags: swift, swift3, uikit, uilabel, uifont

I want to make my text skewed as is in the picture. I have the required font file. How do I achieve this in Swift 3? Thanks in advance!

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can apply a 2D transformation to any UIView subclasss instance. If `label` is your UILabel, then:

```
label.transform = CGAffineTransform(a: 1.0, b: tan(-0.5), c: 0.0, d: 1.0, tx: 0.0, ty: 0.0)
```

The parameters are the values of the matrix that represents the transform. The matrix is

```
|  a  b  0 |
|  c  d  0 |
| tx tx  1 |
```

[skew matrix algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673216/skew-matrix-algorithm) has details on how the parameters can be set. For your skew, b is the important value.

Comment: maybe you wanted to say : `label.tranform = CGAffineTransform(...)`

Comment: Double clicking in Xcode and Safari give different results :)

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 0):

Apply a transform to the UILabel.  A small negative `b` will skew as in your image. Playground example:

```
let container = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 400, height: 200))
let label = UILabel()

label.text = "ADDRESS"
label.sizeToFit()
label.transform = CGAffineTransform(a: 1.0, b: -0.5, c: 0, d: 1.0, tx: 0, ty: 20)

container.addSubview(label)
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = container

container
```

Answer (score -2):

You can try using `CGAffineTransform affineTransformMakeShear()` to give the required skew effect to your UIView.

Comment: `affineTransformMakeShear()` does not exist in the iOS SDK.