# Formula to match a div to a specific "3D" location in a background image

Tags: css, math, 3d, css-transforms

I am trying to liven my background image a little using CSS 3D transformations, the idea was to take the proverbial "landing page full screen background image with a laptop that has a screenshot (in a coffee shop)" and make it more dynamic: Instead of just a screenshot, put an iframe with an actual live HTML page, and make it fit exactly to the photographed item in the background image (e.g. the laptop screen).

**This has 2 challenges:**

1. ability to calculate the location of points in the background image solely based on the screen size
2. ability to do a 3D rotation that will match the laptop screen in the background image

[image: Background Image Screenshot]

**This is how the background defined:**

```
.splash {
  text-align: center;
  background-position: 50% 20%;
  background-size: cover;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-image: url(/assets/themes/twitter/bootstrap/img/scala_tutorials_screenshot2.jpg);
}
```

**Background image size is: 1280 X 850**

I've managed to somehow overcome some of these requirements but in a very brute force way,

- left position in fixed % worked, probably due to the fact that it's width is larger than it's height
- top position was the hardest: I measured the distance from top of the laptop screen to the top edge of the browser window (it's absolute "top" value) and recorded the screen width and height. and came with a 2 variables formula (using excel, a linear regression trend line and some basic math)

Formula code:

```
 var w = window.innerWidth;
 var h =  window.innerHeight;
 var a = 0.0000146552*h - 0.0245612;
 var b = 0.177328 * h + 9.0294;
 console.log("formula: " + a + " * w + " + b);
 var top =  Math.round(a * w +  b);
 vidEl.style.top = top + "px";
 vidEl.style.height = Math.round((vidEl.offsetWidth / 1.438689132444542)) + "px";
```

**However there are multiple issues with this solution**

1. It doesn't work on all screen resolutions, the background doesn't scale the same as for some resolutions, (especially in 4:3 ratios) the background doesn't grow / shrink as the formula expects
2. It is really tedious work to do this again if let's say I have a different screenshot, the solution is really not generic
3. Even if I know the exact coordinates of the 4 points of the laptop screen in the image, I don't have a way in CSS to simply put a div over it, I had to experiment with `rotateX`, `rotateY` and `rotateZ` (and `perspective-origin`) to be able to match, and the match is not exact
4. Due to some perspective-origin quirks, I need to compensate the larger the screen is which leads to some ugly code like this:

Tweaking hacks (yes, I know it's ugly, and probably can reduce it / merge with the above formula somehow)

```
   if(w >= 1200) {
      if(w < 1400) {
        element.style.top = "-10px";
      } else if (w < 1600) {
        element.style.top = "-13px";
      } else if (w < 1700) {
        element.style.top = "-15px";
      } else if (w < 1800) {
        element.style.top = "-17px";
      } else {
        element.style.top = "-19px";
      } 
    } else {
      element.className = "";
    }
```

**Example:** 
You can see what I have made so far [here](http://scalatutorials.com) *requires screen width above 1200 pixels*

**The question:**

1. Is there a way to have a generic formula, that for any given original location in the background image (e.g. the 4 points of the screen corners), given the background image original size, `background-position` definition, screen width and height to find the new coordinates that match the background image?
2. I'd like instead of doing guesswork on `rotateX`, Y and Z, to be able to automatically calculate the X, Y and Z rotation values, that will rotate a DIV to cover exactly a given set of 4 2D coordinates (e.g. the laptop screen)

Answer (score 3):

I'm sad to see there aren't any answers to this yet.  I like what you're trying to do.  I don't think what I can tell you is complete enough to be an answer, but it's too big for a comment, and will hopefully get you rolling.

First, I think your math will be much easier if you can give the points in the original image for the four vertices (in addition to the original image size).  Because then you can easily figure out where the new points will be, based on what percentage along they are in the original image, e.g.

```
xNew = xOld / originalImageWidth * newImageWidth;
yNew = yOld / originalImageHeight * newImageHeight;
```

I see that you're currently putting as much of your information as possible in the .css file. Can you save the image path and the four original points in the data- attribute of an element somewhere?  This will let you calculate the new points.  Barring that, perhaps cheat and add them as a query string to the url.

Your next problem is angling the image.  I don't think it's a 3D transform - it should more simply be a 2D skew along the x-axis.  Check out [skew matrix algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673216/skew-matrix-algorithm) for the matrix transformation.  You can calculate the scale you used to go from one set of points to the other, and that should make it fairly easy to calculate the skew angle, keeping the bottom left of the image fixed and the top right as the variable to solve for.  You can pass that as a css-transform, and that should give you all the basics you need.

You can also check [Projective transformation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/169902/projective-transformation).  This isn't the answer you need - it takes a skewed angle and turns it into a rectangle - but since you need the opposite functionality, this may give you some ideas.

Again, sorry this isn't a complete answer, but it might get you moving in the right direction.  I can try to talk you through any of this that didn't make sense.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks! one comment in the meantime - skew can't work, I tried, but the screen is a bit tilted to the right, so skew won't match (CSS3 doesn't support a non parallel skew, only possible with rotateX/Y/Z AFAIK)

Comment: @EranMedan It still looks to me like you should be able to accomplish it with skews and zooms.  In the worst case, you can solve for skewY as well.  I'll try and see if I can come up with some equations or solutions later today.  What you want *should* be possible, and shouldn't involve complex 3D transformations.

Comment: The projective transformation linked to is exactly what the OP needs.

Comment: @ScottMermelstein ok, will look into css transform 2D skew again, maybe I missed something as I couldn't get a non parallelogram like result no matter what I tried, thanks!

Comment: @TimothyShields you over estimate my math skills, hardly understood the question there, let alone the answer. But will try. Thanks!